# Graphql-Shield hijacks errors

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, graphql-shield

In the resolver `throw new createError.BadRequest("bad input")` error is hijacked by `Graphql-shield` and shown as

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Not Authorised!",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3
                }
            ],
            "path": [
                "myMutation"
            ],
            "extensions": {
                "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
                "exception": {
                    "stacktrace": [
                        "Error: Not Authorised!",
```

This is the Apollo Server setup

```
    const schema = buildSubgraphSchema([
      { typeDefs: await typeDefs(), resolvers },
    ]);
    const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
      schema: applyMiddleware(schema, permissions),
      context: async ({ req, res }) => new AuthenticatedContext(req, res)
    });
```

How do I return the actual error occuring?

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution on [shield documentation](https://www.graphql-shield.com/docs/shield):

```
const permissions = shield({
    Query: {
        ...
    },
    Mutation: {
        ...
    },
}, {allowExternalErrors: true});
```

The ***allowExternalErrors*** option is defaulted to be false according to the documentation.